# How do I find the solution(s) to my second-degree equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, quadratics

> Solve the second-degree equation $x^2 - 3x=4$

My attempt : 
$$
\begin{align}
x^2-3x &= 4\\
x(x-3) &= 4\\
x-3 &= 4 \\
x &= 7\\
\end{align}
$$

I managed to solve one part of this problem but that one part is wrong. I don't understand how to solve for $x$, when $x(x-3) = 4$. I can solve for the $x$ inside the bracket but I don't know how to solve the one outside the bracket and the $x$ I solved for inside the bracket is somehow wrong.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you solving for $x$, or are you trying to find the domain of this function? Could be more clear on what the entire question is asking? Thanks.

Comment: ..........x is the domain :|

Comment: What do you want to do ? The title of your question seems to be unrelated to your question

Comment: Some comments on your specific work: How do you conclude from $x(x-3)=4$, that $x-3=4$? This isn't necessarily the case, $x\cdot x=4$ does not mean that $x=4$. To solve the equation in this case, you'd have to use the quadratic formula, or you can complete the square. (But solving that equation is of no use to the problem)

Comment: If you apply the null factor law. You wouldn't really need the quadratic formula.

Comment: @BusyAnt It's not unrelated. I am trying to find the domain (which is x) that when I input gives me the output 4.

Comment: @jame_smith So you're not interested in the whole domain of $f$ but only the value(s) of $x$ for which $f(x)=4$?

Comment: OK That's not what I understood from "domain". This makes more sense now

Comment: @Workaholic Yes. I only need the values that make f(x) = 4.

Comment: What you tried to apply is something like $x(x-4)=0\implies x-4=0$, but even this would not be correct because in the case $x=0$ , we cannot divide the equation by $x$.

Comment: I edited the question so that people who stumble upon this later will not be confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x(x-3)=4$$
$$x^2-3x-4=0$$
$$(x-4)(x+1)=0$$

Are you able to complete the rest?

Extra comment: In your working, from $x(x-3)=4$, we cannot conclude that $(x-3)=4$.

Extra comment 2: note that $$(x-a)(x-b)=x^2-(a+b)x+ab$$

Hence to recover $a$ and $b$, I tried for factor of $-4$ where the sum is equal to $3$.

For general quadractic equation, you can complete the square or use the quadractic formula.

Comment: You should explain how the factorization can be found.

Answer (score 1):

*Guessing* the solution can be hard if you're not used to it. Here's something to help you understand how [SiongthyeGoh](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/306553/siongthyegoh) found it.

Let $f$ be defined by :

$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x) = x^2-3x
$$

We want to find every $x$ so that $f(x)=4$. Let's solve it !

$$
\begin{align}
x^2-3x &= 4&  x^2-3x ~~\text{ begins like }~~ x^2-3x+\frac94=\left(x-\frac32\right)^2\\
\left(x-\frac32\right)^2-\frac94 &= 4 &\text{factorizing with this remarkable identity}~~~~~~~~\\
\left(x-\frac32\right)^2 &= \frac{25}4 & 4+\frac94= \frac{16}4+\frac94 = \frac{25}4~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\\
x-\frac32 &= \pm\sqrt{\frac{25}4} &\text{be careful with } \pm \text{ when removing the square !}\\
x &= \frac32 \pm\frac52 & \sqrt{25}=5 ~~\text{ and }~~ \sqrt{4}=2 ~~\text{ so }~~ \sqrt{\frac{25}4}=\frac52~~~~~~~~~\\
x = 4 ~~&\text{ or }~~ x = -1 & \frac32+\frac52=\frac82=4 ~~~~\text{ and }~~~~ \frac32-\frac52=\frac{-2}2=-1
\end{align}
$$

---

**This is the best way that I know to solve equations like this where you need no theory.** All you need to remember is that you need to do :

$$
x^2+bx~~~~
\longrightarrow
~~~~\left(x+\frac{b}2\right)^2-\left(\frac{b}2\right)^2
$$

This is called using the canonical form.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2-3x=4$ can be solved by using the pq-formula :

$x^2-3x-4=0$

$x_1=\frac{3}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{9}{4}+4}=4$

$x_2=\frac{3}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{9}{4}+4}=-1$

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have found something new!!

I am going to tell you a new formula:

Any Quadratic Polynomial $ax^2$ + $bx$ + $c$ = $0$ , whose roots are $\alpha$ and  $\beta$, You just find

$$D = (am)^2$$

for  some complex $m$. D is the discriminant given by $b^2 -4ac$.

Then put $m$ in this equation

$$\alpha = (\frac{-b}{a} + m)\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\beta = (\frac{-b}{a} - m)\frac{1}{2}$$

You will get your roots!

Let's Try:

$$x^2- 3x- 4$$

$a=1$

$b= -3$

$c=-4$

Now,

$$D = (am)^2$$

$D = (-3)^2 - 4(1)(-4)$

$D = 9 + 16$

$D =25$

$$25=[(1)(m)]^2$$

$$25 = m^2$$

$$m =5$$

It's easy now

$$\alpha = (\frac{3}{1} + 5)\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\beta = (\frac{3}{1} - 5)\frac{1}{2}$$

The roots would be:

$$\alpha = 4$$
$$\beta = -1$$

You need to remember only these three

> $$D = (am)^2$$
>   $$\alpha = (\frac{-b}{a} + m)\frac{1}{2}$$
>   $$\beta = (\frac{-b}{a} - m)\frac{1}{2}$$

Note: I did not take $m=\pm 5$. I am putting that in $\alpha$ and $\beta$. This gives even the Complex roots also, you can try.

I derived this formula yesterday

!!

Comment: You pretty much re-discovered the classic way of calculating 2nd-degree polynomial roots. Good job ! :)

Comment: Thanks. I have not told you the derivation how I found $m$ there